# jQuery Deprecation Notice jqxhr.success()

Tags: jquery

#### I recently saw a deprecation notice on the jQuery website.

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To
>   prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(),
>   jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

---

I am currently coding as below:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '...',
  success: function(){
    alert('AJAX successful');
  }
});
```

I am planning to use jQuery 1.8+

Should I just change the `success` key into `done` as:

```
$.ajax({
      url: '...',
      done: function(){
        alert('AJAX successful');
      }
    });
```

?

Comment: No. Those are internal options and will work fine. The deprecation notice is for the jqXHR callback methods.

Comment: thanks. i am going to delete this question or this will be useful to someone??

Comment: I think someone might find it useful....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For instance, if you have any of these:

```
$.ajax({url: '...'}).success(function(){
    alert('AJAX successful');
});
$.ajax({url: '...'}).error(function(){
    alert('AJAX ERROR');
});
$.ajax({url: '...'}).complete(function(){
    alert('AJAX complete');
});
```

You would have to change it to:

```
$.ajax({url: '...'}).done(function(){
    alert('AJAX successful');
});
$.ajax({url: '...'}).fail(function(){
    alert('AJAX ERROR');
});
$.ajax({url: '...'}).always(function(){
    alert('AJAX complete');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, It is hard to understand why the `.always` is a replacement for `.complete`. (meaning wise)

Comment: @SenuraDissanayake because the `.always` will execute regardless of the status of the call (failure / success)

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, and jQuery 1.8 came out ages ago - but to help Googlers like me who are upgrading ancient applications to 3.0, I thought I'd chime in for clarification.

This is valid in versions jQuery 1.8+:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/endpoint",
    type: "POST",
    data: myData,
    success: function(json){
        console.log("success");
        console.log(json);
    },
    error: function(jqxhr){
        console.log("failure");
        console.log(jqxhr.responseText);                    
    }
});
```

This is NOT valid in versions jQuery 1.8+. It has been removed in 3.0:

```
var promise = $.ajax({
    url: "/api/endpoint",
    data: myData,
    method: "POST"
});
                    
promise.success(function(json){
    console.log("function not defined!"); // same for .error and .complete
});
```

See @DevIshOne's answer or the [jQuery AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for how to account for this. You simply have to rename to `done()`, `fail()`, and `always()` respectively, or rewrite the code as per my first code block.