# Property 'success' does not exist - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have implemented a function to log-out. My code is the following:

```
logout() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'exampleURL',
        async: false
    }).success(function () {
        alert('You have been logged out'); 
    }).complete(function () {
        location.reload();
    });
}
```

But I get an error:

> [ts] Property 'success' does not exist on type 'jqXHR'

I have previously imported `JQuery`

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the answer here: [jQuery Deprecation Notice jqxhr.success()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698060/jquery-deprecation-notice-jqxhr-success)

Success was deprecated, you should use '[done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)' instead

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation says](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **Deprecation Notice**: The `jqXHR.success()`, `jqXHR.error()`, and `jqXHR.complete()` callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use `jqXHR.done()`, `jqXHR.fail()`, and `jqXHR.always()` instead.

They've actually been *deprecated* for years. It's just in v3 they were finally actually removed. Clearly the `.d.ts` file for jQuery no longer has them (either because it's based on v3, or it leaves out deprecated methods from earlier versions), so TypeScript tells you those properties don't exist.